# Data return is undefined vue.js?

Tags: vue.js

i have a problem i don't understand why i can't recover my recette.
My route at node is ok i have my good res ut at vue my code don't work my res is undefined.
What I am trying to do is to filter my recipes by retrieving only the recipes which have as category recipe 1. I made a route on node which works and which returns me exactly what I want but at the level of view i have a problem.

NODE.JS

```
router.get("/recette_light", (req, res) => {
    db.cat_recette
        .findOne({
            where: { id: req.body.id },
            include: { all: true },
        })
        .then((cat_recette) => {
            if (cat_recette) {
                res.status(200).json({
                    cat_recette: cat_recette,
                });
            } else {
                res.json("il n'y a pas de cat_recettes");

            }
        })
        .catch(err => {
            res.json(err);
        });
});
```

VUE.JS

```
<div>
    <navbar_user />
    <mylight :recette="recette" :user="user" />
    <myfooter />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import navbar_user from "../components/navbar_user";
import mylight from "../components/light";
import myfooter from "../components/myfooter";

export default {
  name: "",
  data() {
    return {
      recette: "",
      user: "",
    };
  },
  components: {
    navbar_user,
    mylight,
    myfooter,
  },
  created: function() {
    this.axios
      .get("http://localhost:3000/recette/rec_recette/:1")
      .then((res) => {
        (this.cat_recette.recette = res.data.recette),
          this.axios
            .get(
              "http://localhost:3000/user/rec_user/" +
                localStorage.getItem("email")
            )
            .then((res) => {
              this.user = res.data.user;
            });
      });
  },
};
```

Thank you for your help i'm novice

Answer (score 0):

On the frontend, you are making an HTTP request with the `GET` method, which has no `body`. On the backend, `req.body.id` will be `undefined` because there is no request body in the first place.

So you have several options:

> First: use a `POST` request on the front end

```
axios({
  method: 'POST',
  url:"http://localhost:3000/recette/rec_recette",
  headers: {}, 
  data: {
    id: 'votre_id_ici', // This is the body part
  }
});
```

The backend code to handle the post request:
(Use async/await to make the code cleaner)

```js
router.post('/recette_light', async (req, res) => {

    try {
        // Assuming you are searching for your recette using MongoDB doc.id
        const cat_recette = await db.cat_recette.findById(req.body.id);
        // If there are no matching docs.
        if (!cat_recette) {
            return res.json("il n'y a pas de cat_recettes");
        }
        // Otherwise send the data to the frontend
        res.status(200).json({ cat_recette: cat_recette, });

    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        res.status(500).json({ msg: 'Server Error', });
    }

});
```

> Second: use the `GET` method still but with URL parameters

```js
axios.get("http://localhost:3000/recette/rec_recette/votre_id_ici")
```

The backend code to handle it:

```js
// Note the /:id at the end
router.get('/recette_light/:id', async (req, res) => {

    try {
        // Assuming you are searching for your recette using MongoDB doc. id
        // Note the req.params.id here not req.body.id
        const cat_recette = await db.cat_recette.findById(req.params.id);
        // If there are no matching docs.
        if (!cat_recette) {
            return res.json("il n'y a pas de cat_recettes");
        }
        res.status(200).json({ cat_recette: cat_recette, });

    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        res.status(500).json({ msg: 'Server Error', });
    }

});
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, I chose the second option. This returns my cat_recette but I would like to include the recipes which are linked by an intermediate table, how can I do this? As in my code before where I put an include?

Comment: I never use mongodb